# Assign name to other rows upon group condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset which is of following nature. I would like to replace the names in "MAKE" column if the column contains "PQR" per unique country.

```
   country     MAKE
1      USA      PQR
2      USA      ABC
3       UK      PQR
4       UK      DEF
5      JPN      DEF
6      JPN      LMN
```

Desired Output:

```
   country    MAKE
1      USA    PQR
2      USA    PQR
3       UK    PQR
4       UK    PQR
5      JPN    OTHERS
5      JPN    OTHERS
```

Comment: Japan seems to have a record with `PQR`.  So why does the make appear as `OTHERS` in your expected output?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is conditional aggregation with analytic functions:

```
SELECT
    country,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN MAKE = 'PQR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY country) > 0
         THEN 'PQR' ELSE 'OTHERS' END AS MAKE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    country;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks for the quick solution. It works!!